# How to make a JSON formatted string which is retrieved by AJAX into a table like format

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am new to web programming and have been having a lot of trouble with using AJAX to parse as a string and create a table.

```
[{"source":"1","name":"random","amount":"5"},{"source":"1","name":"random","amount":"5"}]
```

This is how the data is parsed as I used the code from W3SCHOOLS but adapted it to my situation
I used the JSON stringify command to change it to a string also.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp
Based on the data above which has been retrieved by a AJAX code I am having troubles creating a table based on those results.

Comment: I think i may have copied it wrong but you are right

Comment: Large chunks of code go in the question and should be formatted, not comments.

Comment: `This is my code`  Click the edit button, and modify you question instead of posting a comment.

Comment: [edit] your question, never add code in comments, it's __unreadable__.

Comment: Sorry Im a bit new  to this

Comment: If you want to construct a table then there is not a requirement of `var data= JSON.stringify(myObj);`. Only `var myObj = JSON.parse(this.response);` is enough.

Comment: If i do that the <p> with id demo is assigned nothing

Comment: I think, my answer is sufficient to help you. I am not sure about your request URL. Just click on the link (to w3Schools code editor) that I have updated in my answer and try to change the parameters. Finally, implement based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your `myObj` in a format like table, then there is nothing that automatically converts from an object to table format built into html/javascript.

You could use some lib's to do this, but for something simple the below might be a start for you.

```js
const myObj = [{"source":"1","name":"random","amount":"5"},{"source":"1","name":"random","amount":"5"}];

const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");

myObj.forEach(r => {
  const tr = document.createElement("tr"); 
  ["source", "name", "amount"].forEach(f => {
    const td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerText = r[f];
    tr.appendChild(td);
  });
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
});
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>Source</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider some front end libraries to generate table like [jquery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) or write your own implementation in pure JavaScript if you need something simpler.

Comment: would the <table> need to be with the html tags?

Comment: That depends on context in which you are creating such table. 
But at the end of the day it should be in <html> tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `JSON.stringify` does not create a table. It creates a json string of an object. you need to create a table yourself by appending tr elements to a table or tbody tag like so:

```js
const json = JSON.parse('[{"source":"1","name":"random","amount":"5"},{"source":"1","name":"random","amount":"5"}]');

// querySelector is used to find an html element
// '#' means to search for an id so
// '#myTable' means to search to an element with the id 'myTable'
const tbody = document.querySelector('#myTable');

for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  // First we need to create the td elements.
  const source = document.createElement('td');
  source.innerText = json[i]['source'];
  const name = document.createElement('td');
  name.innerText = json[i]['name'];
  const amount = document.createElement('td');
  amount.innerText = json[i]['amount'];
  
  //Then we need to create a tr to containt the tds
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.appendChild(source);
  tr.appendChild(name);
  tr.appendChild(amount);
  
  //Finaly we need to add our tr to our tbody.
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>source</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>amount</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <!-- the id is used to later refer to this tbody. -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just pasting a live working example for your help, you can modify based on your requirements. Actually, I think its a quick way to help someone. I am using a fake REST service available at https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/.

> I have already it in a page at https://hygull.github.io/pages/animations/ajax_data_fetch.html. If you wish you can inspect and see the code in body inside `<script>` & `</script>`. It is exactly like what you want. Just a little change required is, use `source`, `name`, `amount` in place of `id`, `title`, `body` etc. Also change the request URL.

Here is the example that you can modify and run at https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G2FBIOPTDIQ6.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<h2>POSTS EXAMPLE - RENDER RESPONSE FROM FAKE REST API</h2>
<a href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/">https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/</a>
<hr>
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Body</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <!-- TABLE BODY -->
  <tbody id="tbody">
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script>
function setTable(){
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            posts = JSON.parse(this.responseText)

            var postsText=""

            for (var i=0; i < posts.length; i++){
                postsText += "<tr>" + "<td>" + posts[i].id + "</td><td>" + posts[i].title + "</td><td>" + posts[i].body + "</td></tr>";
            }

            document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML = postsText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

setTable(); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```